# Android + Google App Engine connection

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, cloud

I'm working on connecting an android app in Java with google app engine. This is my first time doing it. I watched and did the same thing that it was done in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U

I have been working and I'm getting the same problem. When creating the project and running it, it runs but it shows me a message that I have to create/add an account, I already register it when creating the project. When I enter my gmail account info it shows me a message saying: "Can not connect with the server". I'm not sure what it is happening, please a ed help on it, thanks for you time and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That video is awesome, but there's some useful documentation for [AppEngine Connected Android apps](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android.html) too.  Specifically in the [Creating A New Project](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_create_project.html) section, it explicitly states,

> Important: You must sign up for a C2DM account using the same Google account that you use for the Android application you are developing and for the GPE plugin.

You can go back and edit things later so that the account you're logging into the app with is separate from the role account being used for C2DM.  But for the code generated by the plugin, they have to be the same account.  Also, don't forget you actually have to [sign up for C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html), as it isn't enabled in all accounts by default.

Answer (score 3):

Careful C2DM is deprecated in favor of [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) and the latest Google plugin doesn't have the wizard for creating a App engine connected android project